# Url rewriting with php?

Tags: php, url, seo, url-rewriting

Ok, let's say i need to use seo urls. How could i manage the following pattern:

```
www.mysite.com/{context}/{mode}/
```

That allows get variables declared as follow:

```
www.mysite.com/{context}/{mode}/{var}/{val}/{var2}/{val2}...
```

For example:

```
www.mysite.com/user/view/id/123
```

?

**Solution?, How to do that?**

A possibly solution could be the following:
All url are redirected to www.mysite.com/index.php.
In the index.php file i divide the url by `$u = explode($ulr, '/');`: ignoring `$u[0]` and considering `$u[1]` as the context, `$u[2]` as the mode and eventual `$u[3], $u[4]...` as couples of var-values like get system `index.php?var=val`.
By knowing the context and the mode the right file is included and everybody is happy.

- How could i get the url (es: www.mysite.com/user/view/id/123) or just the last part (es: user/view/id/123)?
- Is this system has any cons?

Answer (score 0):

The solution i did used is:

*.htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #Rewrite the URI if there is no file or folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

url_manager (only for root files: www.mysite.com/index.php; to use it inside a folder (www.mysite.php/folder/index.php) add +1 to every numeric key and to $i)

```
function urlFile()
{
    $url = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    $context = $url[1];
    $mode = $url[2];
    return "{$context}_{$mode}.php";
}

function get($string)
{
    $url = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    unset($url[0], $url[1], $url[2]);

    $i = 3;
    foreach ($url as $u)
    {
        $get[$url[$i]] = $url[$i + 1];
    }

    return $get[$string];
}
```

Comment: and what if I done `www.mysite.php/functions.php%00` make sure you sanitize them inclusions. - http://ddxhunter.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/lfis-exploitation-techniques/